# Flutter FontAwesome Icons not contain all icons

Tags: flutter, font-awesome

I am learning flutter and I use fontAwesomeIcons.

Is there any way to use add/implement thin or outlined version of FontAwesome icons for flutter application ?

[multiple house icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gCf7.png)

[as you can see not listed in suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spJby.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have buy pro version or you can download svg image and use it

Answer (score 0):

That's because the other versions of 'house' are only included in the 'Pro version' of FontAwesome. And these are obviously not included in the public flutter package of FontAwesome.

If you have a license for 'Pro Version' then have a look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter#enable-pro-icons).